# What is TryParse and Request.Form doing in this line of C# code?

Tags: c#, tryparse, request.form

What does this line of code do? I'm relatively new to C# and I've been trying to figure it out by reading about TryParse and Request.Form, however, I think a more comprehensive explanation would help me.

`int.TryParse(Request.Form["yearhidden"], out year);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TryParse` is taking the value from `Request.Form["yearhidden"]`

`Request.Form["yearhidden"]` is a form field in your html called `yearhidden`.

`TryParse` then attempts to parse it into an integer value.  It returns `True` if it was successful, `False` if not.

The value is stored in the variable `year`

Answer (score 3):

[`Request.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) provides the form element posted to the HTTP request.

[`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) attempts to take this value and convert it to an integer.

In this case, you're taking the `"yearhidden"` form element's value, and attempting to convert it to an integer, which gets set in the `year` variable.

Note that you'd typically check the return value of `int.TryParse`, and handle the case where a non-numeric value was passed into the `yearhidden` variable.

Answer (score 2):

`int.TryParse` returns a boolean that represents whether or not the method was able to parse the first parameter, `Request.Form["yearhidden"]`, into an integer.

If it is able to successfully parse the value, the value of the second parameter, `year`, will be set to the value.

`Request.Form` contains all of the information within an html form element that was sent in a given request.

`out` is a keyword that forces arguments to be passed by reference.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)